# Frida il2cppbridge access violation when trying method Add or Insert at System.Collections.Generic.List`1 (List<int>)

Tags: javascript, frida, il2cpp

I am using [Frida il2cppbridge](https://github.com/vfsfitvnm/frida-il2cpp-bridge) and having the problem that I'm getting always access violation error when trying to add values to generic list.
What I'm doing wrong?

```
let list = Il2Cpp.corlib.class("System.Collections.Generic.List`1")
let int = Il2Cpp.corlib.class("System.Int32")
let listInt = list.inflate(int).new()
                     
listInt.method(".ctor").invoke()
listInt.method("Add").invoke(1)
```

or also if I get the list from internal like:

```
// return type is List<int>
let list = anyClass.method<Il2Cpp.Object>("getList").invoke()
                     

list.method("Add").invoke(1)
```

Getting always the same error, doesn't matter if I try method `Add`, `Insert` or `set_Item`

Error:

> access violation accessing 0x3e8
> at invokeRaw (il2cpp/structs/method.ts:233)
> at  (src/index.ts:18)
> at call (native)
> at  (il2cpp/structs/method.ts:354)

Methods like `get_Count` works fine.

Comment: One possibility is that you supply the constant `1` as argument and not an `System.Int32`.  Normally wrapping of primitive types is often performed automatically by the compiler - but on Frida/il2cppbridge there is no compiler, so you have to do these operations on your own.

Comment: I think you're right but if I create a `System.Int32` variable and then use `TryParse` for example to set it, inside the `Add` method I get the message that I'm using wrong type and that I need type `number` or any other il2cpp type.